# Algolia: Change label in currentRefinements widget

Tags: javascript, widget, algolia, instantsearch.js

I'm using the `currentRefinements` widget to let users select only new products.

The output of that attribute is `true` or `false`.

Here's my current code:

```
instantsearch.widgets.toggleRefinement({
    container: '#facet-new',
    attribute: 'new',
    //on: 'New products',
    templates: {
        labelText: 'New products',
    },
}),
```

If I uncomment the line

```
on: 'New products',
```

The widget wont work anymore.

But if not, the `currentRefinements` widget only shows `true` or `false` as label.

Is there any way to change that label?

Comment: `on` is meant to accept only a boolean value (true/false) to let the widget know when to show the "on" state based on the value of the attribute `new`.  The `labelText` value is suppose to show the proper label for you. When you change to `on: true` (or false, depending) do you get the proper label?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It shows `true` as well